# Leaflet js add/remove

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a scenario. I want a marker to add polygon and remove polygon on giving area coordinates. For example, one office is in Australia handles near countries like South Africa etc. I want to click on the Australia marker then South Africa should highlight with polygon boundaries. when I click again it should remove the highlighted countries. Is that possible with leaflet and jquery toggle method.

Thanks

Comment: Probably. But without knowing anything about your data or your code, it's hard to be any more helpful.

Comment: here is link on plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/FTQD7WYjy9ZxYGvkwihI?p=preview

Comment: Here is link on jsfiddle as well thanks in advance. https://jsfiddle.net/magtechpro/uqwrcf6g/6/